# Resetting ROW_NUMBER count based on 3 month gap in date

Tags: sql, sas, teradata, row-number

Looking for a solution on how to start the ROW_NUMBER count over if there is a gap in a date field (**clm_line_srvc_strt_dt**) of more than 3 months.

Currently using the following for the row count:

```
,ROW_NUMBER() 
OVER(PARTITION BY c.src_sbscrbr_id
, c.src_mbr_sqnc_nbr
, cl.hlth_srvc_cd 
, df.serv_prov_id
ORDER BY c.src_sbscrbr_id
, c.src_mbr_sqnc_nbr
, cl.hlth_srvc_cd 
, df.serv_prov_id
, cl.clm_line_srvc_strt_dt) as rncnt
```

For example:
Member ID 011 has three records with the clm_line_srvc_strt_dt field being 28Dec2017, 28Apr2018, and 28Jul2018.

Currently the row count for these 3 lines are **1, 2, 3**.

The row count should reset to 1 with the 28Apr2018 line since the gap between Dec 28 2017 and Apr 28 2018 is greater than 3 months. So it should be **1, 1, 2**, with the third line continuing to count since the gap between 28Apr2018 and 28Jul2018 is not greater than 3 months.

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teradata supports a proprietary extension to Windowed Aggregates, RESET WHEN, which adds a kind of dynamic partition:

```
Row_Number() 
Over(PARTITION BY c.src_sbscrbr_id
                , c.src_mbr_sqnc_nbr
                , cl.hlth_srvc_cd 
                , df.serv_prov_id
     ORDER BY  cl.clm_line_srvc_strt_dt
     -- restart the row number when the previous date is more than 3 months ago
     RESET WHEN Min(clm_line_srvc_strt_dt)
                Over (PARTITION BY c.src_sbscrbr_id
                                 , c.src_mbr_sqnc_nbr
                                 , cl.hlth_srvc_cd 
                                 , df.serv_prov_id
                      ORDER BY cl.clm_line_srvc_strt_dt
                      ROWS BETWEEN 1 Preceding AND 1 Preceding) 
               < Add_Months(cl.clm_line_srvc_strt_dt, -3)) AS rncnt
```

Based on the error message in Gordon's answer your Teradata version doesn't support LAG, yet (must be 16.10+). The MIN is the same as:

```
                LAG(clm_line_srvc_strt_dt)
                Over (PARTITION BY c.src_sbscrbr_id
                                 , c.src_mbr_sqnc_nbr
                                 , cl.hlth_srvc_cd 
                                 , df.serv_prov_id
                      ORDER BY cl.clm_line_srvc_strt_dt)
```

Btw, there's no need to ORDER by the same columns you already use in PARTITION (within a partition it's the same value anyway)

Comment: Thanks @dnoeth, I wasn't aware of the windowed aggregates (RESET when) extension. This worked perfectly for what I was trying to accomplish. And you were right about LAG, my company is on Teradata 15.10. I'll make sure to post the DB and version I'm using next time.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the Lagged variable approach in data step. I have used sample data:

```
data sample;
input Mem_Id clm_line_srvc_strt_dt date9.;
format clm_line_srvc_strt_dt date9.;
datalines;
1011 28Dec2017
1011 28Apr2018
1011 28Jul2018
1011 28Aug2018
2012 15Apr2017
2012 15Jul2017
2012 15Oct2017
;
run;

proc sort data=sample; by Mem_Id clm_line_srvc_strt_dt; run;

data sample1;
 set sample;
  by Mem_id clm_line_srvc_strt_dt;
  Retain RowCount 0;

  diff=intck('MONTH',lag(clm_line_srvc_strt_dt),clm_line_srvc_strt_dt);
  if first.Mem_id then RowCount=1;
  else if diff<=3 then rowcount=rowcount+1;
  drop diff;
run; 

proc print data=sample1; run;
```

Comment: This was great. Thanks Rhythm.

Comment: Great!! happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You would do this using a cumulative sum and `lag()`.  The idea is:

```
sum(case when cl.clm_line_srvc_strt_dt < prev_clm_line_srvc_strt_dt + interval '3 month'
         then 0 else 1
    end) over (partition by c.src_sbscrbr_id, c.src_mbr_sqnc_nbr, cl.hlth_srvc_cd, df.serv_prov_id
               order by cl.clm_line_srvc_strt_dt
              ) as rncnt
from (select . . .,
             lag(cl.clm_line_srvc_strt_dt) over (partition by c.src_sbscrbr_id, c.src_mbr_sqnc_nbr, cl.hlth_srvc_cd, df.serv_prov_id) as prev_clm_line_srvc_strt_dt
      . . .
     ) . . .
```

Comment: Thanks for that info Gordon. Would there be some kind of formatting for the date field being used in order to use the sum or lag functions? I'm getting an error ERROR: Teradata execute: Syntax error: Data Type "clm_line_srvc_strt_dt" does not match a Defined Type name.

Comment: @JoeX . . . You have to use the appropriate Teradata logic to specify a difference of 3 months.  Your question didn't have a database tag when I answered.